# Safari does not load the javascript on my website

Tags: javascript, safari

I have created a website that works fine on chrome. However, when trying to view the website on safari the website does not load the javascript for some reason and I have no idea what to do.

You can view the website [here](https://newhomescrowd.com/)

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you enabled web inspector on Safari, to have a console/debugger?
Javascript is enabled on your Safar browser?

Comment: @Ludo I don't have a mac but I have an iPhone and the javascript is not loading

Comment: Have you got any special characters in you urls ?

Comment: @Ludo No Sir, I honestly do know what's going on?

Comment: As @Xufox said, please  add some information to describe what does not work. I mean How do you know that javascript does not load? Is it all javascript functions ?

Comment: hi @JafarOcean can you update best answer plz

Answer (score 1):

Safari is extremely picky with syntax errors (which will give you a notorious blank white screen), including HTML parsing errors, for which Chromium will compensate by overlooking them. Read your code closely and ensure no syntax errors. It would be helpful to have an example.

Comment: Hi Sua, I do have an example the website I am talking about is here (https://newhomescrowd.com/). Sorry, I can't prove enough detail. I have a Windows Computer so I don't have Safari. Can you check the console to see if there is an error?

Comment: here's the error when I open Safari: 
`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name='inf_field_Email`

I suspect that when you fix that, your website will behave as expected